Why do we need to apply Lorentz transformation twice when transforming the electromagnetic field tensor and what does it mean?
I would understand if this was following the defined way of lowering or raising of the indices of a four vector after a Lorentz transformation.
$$F^{'}_{\mu\nu} = \Lambda_{\mu}^{\alpha} \Lambda_{\nu}^{\beta} F_{\alpha\beta} $$
But then it is only strictly following the rules? Why and how do we interpret the results to be the quantity observed from another frame of reference (according to how we choose the Lorentz boost)? I do not understand how the underlying physical contents are transforming along the way.
Please someone help.

I do not understand how the underlying physical contents are transforming along the way. Wikipedia explains what this Lorentz transformation of $F$ implies for the Lorentz transformation of $\mathbf E$ and $\mathbf B$.

I would understand if this was following the defined way of lowering or raising of the indices… This Lorentz transformation has nothing to do with raising or lowering indices. Observe that both tensor indices of the field are lower in both reference frames.

Make sure you understand that the right side of the transformation represents the sum of 16 terms, due to the Einstein summation convention. For a general Lorentz transformation, each of the 16 field components in the primed frame is some linear combination of the 16 components in the unprimed frame.

Are you trying to learn the covariant formulation of electromagnetism without a textbook? Any decent textbook should make all of this clear.

We are not applying it twice, what happens is that this is how rank 2 tensors transform. A rank n tensor will transform like
$$
F^{'}_{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n} = \Lambda_{a_1}^{b_1} \Lambda_{a_2}^{b_2} \dots \Lambda_{a_n}^{b_n}F_{b_1,b_2,\dots,b_n}
$$
And this does not means $n$ transformations, but just one. I think you should face it more like a mathematical rule, like why $(a+b)^2= a^2+2ab+b^2$ and not simple $(a+b)^2= a^2+b^2$? The last is nice, but the first gives the right value.
If you want to understand why the electromagnetic tensor is a rank 2 tensor, remember that is defined through the four vector potential as
$$
F_{\mu,\nu}=\partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu
$$
Despite the four vector $A_\mu$ being a rank 1 tensor and transform by one application of the Lorentz transformation matrix, the operator $\partial_\mu$ is also a rank 1 tensor, so you need to transform it too. It will gives
$$
F^{'}_{\mu,\nu} =\partial_\mu^{'} A_\nu^{'} - \partial_\nu^{'} A_\mu^{'}= (\Lambda_{\mu}^{\alpha}\partial_\alpha)(\Lambda_{\nu}^{\beta} A_\beta) - (\Lambda_{\nu}^{\beta}\partial_\beta)(\Lambda_{\mu}^{\alpha} A_\alpha)\\
= \Lambda_{\mu}^{\alpha} \Lambda_{\nu}^{\beta}(\partial_\alpha A_\beta - \partial_\beta A_\alpha)
$$
And we recover the transformation rule for rank 2 tensors.
